# Dishwasher safe lids for copper cookware?

Tags: pan, pot, kitchen, copper-cookware

I have a copper cookware set.  I understand that the copper portion isn't dishwasher safe, but what about the lids?  I assume since they have no copper on them, they are dishwasher safe.

[My Cookware Set](http://www.cutleryandmore.com/calphalon-tri-ply-copper/premier-cookware-set-p14081?gclid=CIaWhorXjK0CFQXd4Aodu30OoA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those lids appear to be stainless steel, and as such would be dishwasher safe.